# Internet with only a wired connection?

Tags: internet

I have a non-data plan with my Windows phone, and besides, when I'm out of the country, roaming charges are too great to use the cellular network.

So when I'm in a hotel room that has a hi-speed internet connection via ethernet cable, is there any way I can use that to connect my phone to the internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet will be to get a travel/mini wireless router. They are small and will let you share your ethernet connection (and sometimes other internet connection types) with your phone.

You will need to shop around and find the best one for you. Amazon has quite a good [selection](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006DEBYWU).

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Skype account.  Install Skype on win8.  Then put some $s into your Skype account.  You can use it to make voip calls on Skype rates.

Comment: Was this answer left on the wrong question? I can't see how it addresses this one.

Comment: jac - i'd say its a work around to him getting hit with roaming charges and getting a cheap cell option.  while its not how he can connect his phone to to the internet (not possible that I know of) it is how he can make calls off the internet, which is the end game.  And Skype will let you mask your own cell number over the Skype one, so you get a great effect on outbound calls.  Comment or answer.  Doesn't bother me either way.

Comment: ah, didn't think of that as a possible end game, thought he just wanted a data connection for email/etc on the phone.